# Use the Euclidean algorithm to show 74 and 105 are relatively prime. Be sure to identify at least one solution to the equation 105s+74t=1

Tags: abstract-algebra

Use the Euclidean algorithm to show 74 and 105 are relatively prime. Be sure to identify at least one solution to the equation 105s+74t=1.

1)Which congruence classes in the ring $Z_{12}$ have multiplicative inverses.

2) These classes form a group under multiplication modulo 12. is it cyclic?

TO START:

105=1*74+21

74=8*9+2

9=3*3+0

This is how i showed 105 and 74 are prime.

But i am confused on the second part

am i suppose to find s and t? The only way i know how to find two missing variables is using two equations... What is the other way? Or am i missing something?

part 1) I think i am suppose to look at the group $Z_{12} $ so {1,5,7,11} But i am not sure which of these have the inverse..?

part 2) Yes it is cyclic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll just address the first gcd thing.

$$  \gcd( 105, 74 ) = ???    $$

$$ \frac{ 105 }{ 74 } = 1 +  \frac{ 31 }{ 74 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 74 }{ 31 } = 2 +  \frac{ 12 }{ 31 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 31 }{ 12 } = 2 +  \frac{ 7 }{ 12 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 12 }{ 7 } = 1 +  \frac{ 5 }{ 7 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 7 }{ 5 } = 1 +  \frac{ 2 }{ 5 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 5 }{ 2 } = 2 +  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 2 }{ 1 } = 2 +  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 } $$ 
 Simple continued fraction tableau:
 $$ 
 \begin{array}{cccccccccccccccc}
 & & 1 & & 2 & & 2 & & 1 & & 1 & & 2 & & 2 & \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 1 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }   & &   \frac{ 7 }{ 5 }   & &   \frac{ 10 }{ 7 }   & &   \frac{ 17 }{ 12 }   & &   \frac{ 44 }{ 31 }   & &   \frac{ 105 }{ 74 }  
 \end{array}
 $$

$$ 105 \cdot 31 - 74 \cdot 44 = -1 $$

I like the continued fraction method, it needs no, well, cleverness.

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

If the gcd is larger than one, the continued fraction simply arrives at the fraction in lowest terms. Let's do 105 and 96:

$$  \gcd( 105, 96 ) = ???    $$

$$ \frac{ 105 }{ 96 } = 1 +  \frac{ 9 }{ 96 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 96 }{ 9 } = 10 +  \frac{ 6 }{ 9 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 9 }{ 6 } = 1 +  \frac{ 3 }{ 6 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 6 }{ 3 } = 2 +  \frac{ 0 }{ 3 } $$ 
 Simple continued fraction tableau:
 $$ 
 \begin{array}{cccccccccc}
 & & 1 & & 10 & & 1 & & 2 & \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 1 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 11 }{ 10 }   & &   \frac{ 12 }{ 11 }   & &   \frac{ 35 }{ 32 }  
 \end{array}
 $$ 
 $$  $$ 
 $$ 35 \cdot 11 - 32 \cdot 12 = 1 $$

$$  \gcd( 105, 96 ) = 3  $$
 $$ 105 \cdot 11 - 96 \cdot 12 = 3 $$

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

$$  \gcd( 144, 89 ) = ???    $$

$$ \frac{ 144 }{ 89 } = 1 +  \frac{ 55 }{ 89 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 89 }{ 55 } = 1 +  \frac{ 34 }{ 55 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 55 }{ 34 } = 1 +  \frac{ 21 }{ 34 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 34 }{ 21 } = 1 +  \frac{ 13 }{ 21 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 21 }{ 13 } = 1 +  \frac{ 8 }{ 13 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 13 }{ 8 } = 1 +  \frac{ 5 }{ 8 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 8 }{ 5 } = 1 +  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 5 }{ 3 } = 1 +  \frac{ 2 }{ 3 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 3 }{ 2 } = 1 +  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 2 }{ 1 } = 2 +  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 } $$ 
 Simple continued fraction tableau:
 $$ 
 \begin{array}{cccccccccccccccccccccc}
 & & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & & 2 & \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 1 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 2 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }   & &   \frac{ 5 }{ 3 }   & &   \frac{ 8 }{ 5 }   & &   \frac{ 13 }{ 8 }   & &   \frac{ 21 }{ 13 }   & &   \frac{ 34 }{ 21 }   & &   \frac{ 55 }{ 34 }   & &   \frac{ 144 }{ 89 }  
 \end{array}
 $$ 
 $$  $$ 
 $$ 144 \cdot 34 - 89 \cdot 55 = 1 $$

Comment: OO wow that is a lot easier! Thank you